# Error with function topicmodels::lda in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I'm trying to use LDA model from topicmodels package in R.
I need to measure method's instability so I have generated true parameters from the Dirichlet distribution for w = 3000 words, t = 8 topics and d = 50 documents with approximately 60 words in each one:

```
Theta = t(rdirichlet(d, alpha))

Phi = t(rdirichlet(t, beta))

docs = matrix(0, nrow = d, ncol = w)

for (i in 1:d)  {   
    curn = rnorm(1, mean = 60, sd = 10)    
    for (j in 1:curn)   {
        curt = rdiscrete(1, Theta[,d], 1:t)
        curw = rdiscrete(1, Phi[,curt], 1:w)
        docs[i, curw] = docs[i, curw] + 1
        }
    }
```

So my docs matrix is a sparse matrix d * w and almost all elements are 0 or 1.

Then I need my docs matrix to be an object of the DocumentTermMatrix class to use it in topicmodels:lda():

```
docs = as.DocumentTermMatrix(docs, weighting = weightTf)
```

I need to use Gibbs sampling method, so I write

```
ldafitmodel <- lda(docs, t, method = "Gibbs")
```

And then I get:

> Error in lda.default(docs, t, method = "Gibbs") : 
>     nrow(x) and length(grouping) are different

I guess this topicmodels package uses MASS package, but then this grouping parameter is something I can't control explicitly, can I? Or what do I do wrong with my data?

Please help me!

BR,
Maria

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Your exact problem isn't reproducible because you don't have d, t, w, alpha or beta defined and do not load the appropriate packages for your `rdirichlet()` and `rdiscrete()` function calls. However, I'm pretty sure your problem is calling the `lda()` function from the MASS package - which is for linear discriminate analysis, not latent dirichlet allocation - instead of the `LDA()` function from the topicmodels package. R is case sensitive, so those caps makes a difference. Also as a note, if you think you may be experiencing a simliar problem in the future but with objects that have the exact same name then you can specify the exact object you would like via namespaces in the form of ::, for example `topicmodels::LDA()`.

Anyway, I can't reproduce your example but I think this example should illustrate your error and a working solution.

```
> library(topicmodels)
> data(AssociatedPress)
> docs = AssociatedPress[1:100]
> ldafitmodel <- lda(docs, 4, method = "Gibbs")
Error in lda.default(docs, 4, method = "Gibbs") : 
  nrow(x) and length(grouping) are different
> (ldafitmodel <- LDA(docs, 4, method = "Gibbs"))
A LDA_Gibbs topic model with 4 topics.
```